# having trouble in visual basic

Tags: visual-studio-2012, console

Module Module1

```
Sub Main()
    'program to display whether first number is divisible by second
    Dim a, b As Integer
    Console.WriteLine("enter first number ::")
    Console.ReadLine(a).ToString()
    Console.WriteLine("enter second number ::")
    Console.ReadLine(b).ToString()
    If a Mod b = 0 Then
        Console.WriteLine("numbers are divisible!")
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("numbers are not divisible!")
    End If
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

### End Module

I am having trouble getting past the first if statement. When I execute the program it doesn't display further information it just inputs the values and freezes. I am a newbie in visual basic, but I don't under stand whats going on.

Comment: *if a Mod b==0 By using single = you are basically assigning the value instead of checking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `if a Mod b=0` to `if a Mod b==0` 
By using single = you are basically assigning the value instead of checking